# How to put a fetch request inside a function and wait for the return value when I call the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am using react-native, mongo DB and node js and I need to create some database functions and put them in some modules to be able to reuse them whenever I want. To fetch data from the mongo database, I use the `fetch()` function which returns a promise. So, for all functions that I created that did not return a value, I used `.then` and I faced no problems. On the other side, when I return a value inside a `fetch().then()` function and use this returned value, I get undefined. The code I use for the function looks like:

```
export const getUsers = () => {
  //I cannot use this function because of returning a promise
  fetch("http://1jjsd12zaws.ngrok.io/database/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    });
};
```

Then, when I try to run this code:

```
let users=getUsers();
console.log(users);
```

It prints `undefined`.

What I think is going on is that the `console.log(users)` runs before `getUsers()` returns its value. But I do not know why does this happen and I want it to wait for `getUsers()` to execute then, completes its work.

Comment: `getUsers` has no `return` statement, so of course it returns `undefined`. You need to `return fetch(...)` (plus additional `.then` clauses) inside it, and then call it like `getUsers().then(data => {/* do stuff */})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to return `fetch(..)` inside `getUsers` (that's why you are getting `undefined`)
- You also need to return `res.json()` inside the first `then`
- Since `getUsers` returns a Promise, then you need to use `.then` (or `async/await`) to access the promise value: `getUsers().then(users => {...})`

```js
const getUsers = () => {
  return fetch('http://1jjsd12zaws.ngrok.io/database/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    });
};

getUsers().then(users => console.log(users))
```

Comment: Should I return ```res.json()``` or ```fetch(..)```?

Comment: so you need to return `fetch().then()...` inside `getUsers`, and return `res.json()` inside the first `then`

Comment: It worked thanks a lot. But I do not get what is being returned here. The fetch or the stringified JSON? Is it here returning a fetch firstly, then when I use then method for that fetch I get the next returned value?

Comment: You can look at it this way: when you do `fetch().then(...).then(...)` the result of fetch is passed through the chain of `.then` handlers (the first `then` extract json from the response, then the second `then` stringify the previous value and so on) .. finally when you do `getUsers().then()` you are basically adding another `then` to the chain of `.then`s

Answer (score 0):

Async and await should cover it. The example on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) explains it better than I can and should apply to your use case.